# basic multithreading concept understanding

Tags: multithreading

There is an interview question:

x, y, a, b are all integers and initially zero.
There are two threads.

Thread 1:

```
x=1  a=y
```

Thread 2:

```
y=1 b=x
```

These two threads are running at the same time. What's the possible results of a and b?

My solution:
There are six valid execution sequence because of sequential consistency.

(1) x=1, a=y, y=1, b=x

(2) x=1, y=1, a=y, b=x

(3) x=1, y=1, b=x, a=y

(4) y=1, x=1, a=y, b=x

(5) y=1, x=1, b=x, a=y

(6) y=1, b=x, x=1, a=y

So the possible results are: a = 1, b = 1 or a = 0, b = 1 or a = 1, b = 0
Can anyone help me verify it?

Comment: Where is the guarantee that `x=1` is performed before reading `y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are the 6 possible orders of operations, given the two threads.  Your possible results are also correct.  One of the two operations to set x/y must occur before the corresponding read, so at least one of a/b must be 1.  It is possible for both to be 1.